# How can I confirm focus with a Nikkor 70-300 lens on a D3000?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, manual-focus, nikon-d3000, focus-confirmation

Good day!

I would like to have some suggestion from experienced photographers about following matter:

I have a Nikon D3000 Camera. I bought a Nikkor Lens 70-300mm having not motor inside and unable to have auto focus. Is there any way that I do focus manually, but the correctly focused notification I can get?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a question and answer site, and it works best if each question just has one single question, not several different ones. It's okay to post twice in a row instead of combining questions. Also: on the question title, we generally try to avoid subjective shopping questions like that.

Comment: Hi there, as Matt noted, shopping style questions are generally off topic for us, but the first part of your questions is a good one. I've edited your question to keep the on topic part, but once you get a bit of reputation you can join us in the [chat] room and ask some shopping questions there.

Answer (score 3):

I will just address your first question here - your second question is off-topic.

Your camera will already tell you if the image is in focus: a green circle/dot will appear in the bottom left corner of the viewfinder.

If you want more precision, you can turn on the rangefinder option in the settings menu that will turn the exposure meter (in P, S, and A modes) into a distance indicator.